# VS Code Source control, push with passphrase

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

It is not possible to git push via the GUI on VS Code when you have a passphrase on your ssh key. I didn't find a solution to this. Am I wrong?

Comment: VS Code usually opens a input window at the top middle of the window when it needs input. Isn't that happening?

Comment: @fredrik It is when I set up the https remote. But with SSH it does not work

Comment: It seems they recommend you to use the SSH Agent: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting